# How do you specify the user name VSSConverter.exe should use?

Tags: tfs, vssconverter

I am using VSSConverter.exe to migrate from VSS to TFS (About time too). I am having an issue because the account I am running it under is not on the same domain as the TFS server. Is there any way to tell the VSSConverter.exe tool which server account to use?

For example when I use the tf command line I add the /login:myname,mypassword switch like this:

```
C:> tf dir $\ /login:myname,mypassword etc...
```

Is there some way I can do the same with the VSSConverter.exe?

The error I am getting by is this:

> TF60071: Your user account does not have permission to connect to the Team
>   Found ation Server 'https://www.example.com/tfs/DefaultCollection'.
>   Please contact your Team Foundation Server administrator and request that
>   the appropriate permission be added to your account.

Comment: I went through this process about 2 years ago with my current employer. After a long hard look at what was in VSS it was easy to say that just checking in the base line was the best way to go. No conversion, no history, no comments (they didn't exist anyway). Just open up the projects you want to convert, unbind them from VSS and check them into TFS like a brand new project. Not really answering your question and for that I am sorry but if you are just getting started cutting bait now might save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the comment. I have decided to go ahead anyway. VSSConverter seems to do a reasonable job once it works though my VSS database does not have any Branches or Shared documents in. Still the change history is there and the version labels are also there which will be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSSConverter.exe will try and connect to TFS with the account that it is currently running as. Sometimes that account cannot be added to TFS, or used with TFS - e.g. There is no domain trust between the two domains.

To specify alternate credentials, you can use the windows credential manager to store them. VSSConverter will then try and use these to connect to the server.

In Windows 7, you can do this:

```
Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage Windows Credentials > Add a Windows credential

Network address: www.example.com
User name: DOMAIN\user
Password: Password
```

You can also get to it by going to:

```
Start > Run
Type: **rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr**
```

Comment: Thanks Grant. That has been a big help. At first this didn't work though, but then I realised that I had a number of other user accounts already mapped to that domain. I'm not sure how Windows decides between them but reomoveing then all first solved the issue.